initializeFirestore(app, { ignoreUndefinedProperties: true }) is not working
I have written a Firebase function that throws an error because one of the fields that its updating is undefined.
After some digging search, i would like to use the ignoreUndefinedProperties: true.
My current code in firebase.js
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// assume all other imports and code is correct

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

Attempt 1:
This is more of a workaround inside the function. Creating "if statements" and updating or not updating based on that. That's fine for a low number of fields, as they increase, its problematic.
Attempt 2:
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// assume all other imports and code is correct

initializeFirestore(app, { ignoreUndefinedProperties: true });
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

This hasn't worked. I still get the same error that a certain field is undefined, its as though nothing is different.
Attempt 3:
I saw this answer(the most upvoted answer) and if i understand it correctly, it is initiated either at the beginning of every page(of functions) or the beginning of every function, which I prefer. It hasn't worked, it gives an error of "firebase" is not defined
Any assistance would be appreciated.

You're probably getting "firebase" is not defined because you're mixing the namespaced API with the modular API (see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). Your second attempt is the correct way to enable ignoreUndefinedProperties on the modular API. Other than that, I guess you'll have to provide a minimal reproducible example because I can't see where things are going wrong in your snippets. Make sure you don't make your API keys public in the repro.
